# ASP.NET Gridview - Allow Edit/Update/Delete From Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, datagrid

This site ([here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx)) shows that you may combine a LinqDataSource with a GridView and allow the viewer to edit, update and delete entries.  All you have to do is configure the LinqDataSource, and set the `GridView.DataSource = LinqDatasource`
I'm using Linq2Sql, by the way.

My question is: How do I get the same edit/update/delete behavior from a GridView by using stored procedures to get my datasource?

E.g.

```
void SetTable(GridView myGridView)
{
   FooDataContext myDataContext = new FooDataContext();
   var results = myDataContext.StoredProcedure_1();
   myGridView.DataSource = results;
   myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

The LinqDataSource has properties such as "EnableEdit" and "EnableDelete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do it would be to utilize the SQLDataSource control to use parameterized stored procedures in leu of the LinqDatasource.

[Here](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/SQLDataSource_StoredProcedure_Multiple_Tables_Update.aspx) is an article with an example of utilizing stored procedures for CRUD operaitons using a gridview bound to a sqldatasource.